# Setting hostname of mac Remotely?

Tags: terminal

I would like to know how to set the hostname of another mac remotely as done locally via `sudo scutil --set HostName <new host name>`.

I was in a cowork space in Medellin today and someone had changed my hostname to `iphone-de-diana`. I also would like to know how to prevent this.

PS. I have a 2017 Macbook Pro running Mojave